# javascript in wordpress page editor not working

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I want to place the following code into the editor frame of a single page in Wordpress. My goal is to turn the text white of anything inside a  tag set.

```
<script>
document.getElementsByTagName("strong").style.color = "white";
</script>
```

I've already confirmed that the  tag can take a style. So it works if I edit a single tag to:

```
<strong style="color:white;">Foo</strong>
```

Comment: Okay. And what is your issue? What is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByTagName) is a collection of elements. You need to loop through and set style its elements individually:

```
var strong = document.getElementsByTagName("strong");
for (var i = 0; i < strong.length; i++) {
    strong[i].style.color = "white";
}
```

Or better if you can add `script` tag, then you should also be able just use `style` tag instead of javascript:

```
<style>
strong {
    color: white;
}
</style>
```

Comment: So are you saying that the WP editor frame will allow you to put in a <style> tag even though everything in that frame ends up in the <body>?

Comment: I didn't work with Wordpress, but if it allows `script` tag, then for sure you can insert `style` too. And you can put it in `body` without problem.